# Juddi publish and find service

Tags: java, uddi, juddi

I have successfully set up an Apache Juddi v3 installation (tomcat version) on my computer. What I want now is to publish a service whose WSDL is found at

```
http://localhost:8080/axis2/services/CmmdcService/wsdl
```

To achieve this, I created a standalone Java application (starting from the Juddi documentation) that publishes the service found at the above location.

The publish part looks ok, but then I want to query the juddi database for the service but a field that should contain the found services is always `null` (**getServiceInfos()**). I really don't know what is wrong and I didn't find any good documentation or tutorial about this on the internet.

[Here](http://cid-4423383e1ef9935d.office.live.com/browse.aspx/.Public/Juddi) you can find the sources of the program. Just unarchive it and go to the `./publish` folder. The application is found there.

Comment: I have been trying to publish from a long time, but it seems in the documentation example that there is class called ClassUtil, but I am unable to resolve it to any of the jars the documentation says. Can you please post your registration code along with the jar dependencies.

Comment: ClassUtil is part of the juddi client. Source here http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/juddi/tags/juddi-3.1.3/juddi-client/src/main/java/org/apache/juddi/v3/client/ClassUtil.java?view=markup

Comment: I didnt know what Juddi was till I saw this post. Went over to apache and I have to ask: who the heck designed that page?

Comment: @thejartender it's not really a page but an SVN repository. They don't have to look pretty. Usually, you'd get a plain, unstyled HTML with occasional file downloads but they used ViewVC to make it web-browsable.

Comment: I know I meant the apavhe site for Juddi

Comment: @thejartender At least the site doesn't use the &lt;blink&gt; tag, but it seems to suffer from mid 90's creative color selection.

Answer (score 1):

With out much Apache knowledge, It sounds as if `getServiceInfos()` function is trying to retrieve information from the wrong sub folder when you do a query.  Try changing the location of the search Function so that it will search all folders/locations or a specific folder/location where the database is located.

I could be wrong ( I have limited skills with Apache ).

Good luck, sorry if this confused you or did not help.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Sorry, I misread the question. I'm not sure what search criteria you've specified, but the server didn't return any results.

When using the "approximateMatch" find qualifier, you really need to specify a wildcard character, such as % (any number of characters) or _ (a single character).

Long story short, this is probably a bug that has since been fixed. Try a newer version